# typedef with const and without const qualifier

Tags: c++, c, typedef

```
    typedef void* TVPtr;
    typedef const void* CTVPtr;

const TVPtr func3 (const TVPtr p)
{
    return p;
}

const void* func4 (const void* p)
{
    return p;
}

CTVPtr func5 (CTVPtr p)
{
    return p;
}


int main ()
{
    const uint64_t i = 10;

    func3(&i);  // compilation error here
                // cannot convert argument 1 from 'const uint64_t *' 
                // to 'const TVPtr' Conversion loses qualifiers    
    func4(&i);  // no compilation error
    func5(&i);  // no compilation error
    return 0;

}
```

I do not understand why there is error is one case and not in the other two?

Comment: This would be one of many reasons why you should never hide pointers behind typedefs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const TVPtr
```

means:

```
void * const  //correct
```

**not** this:

```
const void*   //wrong
```

which you seems to think.

---

#### Visualization has power to influence your understanding.

This is one reason why I believe putting `const` after the type is a better practice. So if you have this practice:

```
void const * x;
```

instead of

```
const void * x; //same as void const *x!
```

then it helps with typedef and template.

For example, take this typedef:

```
typedef void* voidptr;
```

Now if you write the following and try to visualize what it is:

```
voidptr const x;
```

then you're more likely to visualize it as:

```
void* const x; //correct
```

which is in fact what it is.

With `const` before the type is counter-intuitive:

```
const voidptr x;
```

seems to be:

```
const void* x; //wrong
```

which is actually wrong — it is still this:

```
 void* const x; //correct
```

So putting `const` after the type helps visualizing the final type.

Comment: I do not think there is any problem with the return type but the input parameter. Secondly, why does it work for the other two func calls func4, func5? My case is whatever that pointer points to is constant and not that pointer is the constant.

Comment: why does const TVPtr means void * const? For that i would have written TVPtr const.

Comment: I want it to interpret it as const void *, what needs to be done?

Comment: Use `const void*`. There is NO way you can use the typedef and mean it `const void*`. You could define another typedef for `const void*` though.

Comment: You could say something horrible like `const typename std::remove_pointer<TVPtr>::type*`, but then why not just say `const void*`.

Comment: @Nawaz you just gave a long explanation of why `void const *` is a good idea and then in comments you suggest `const void *`  >.>

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Good catch. I was actually being conformist, after I saw Abhishek using `const void*` and others who has this practice. Sometime, I save time by saying exactly what they want, especially when I've already said enough.

Answer (score 7):

`const TVPtr` is not `const void*`, it's `void* const`. In other words, it's not a pointer to `const void`, it's a `const` pointer to `void`. Since `i` is declared `const` it will happily bind to a `const void*`, but not a `void* const`, because that discards the `const`ness of the object itself.

Comment: why does it take const TVPtr as void * const? For that i would have written TVPtr const.

Comment: `TVPtr` is a pointer, so adding `const` makes it a `const` pointer. It doesn't inject `const`ness into the type.

Answer (score 0):

func3 expects a non const type and promises not to change it via the const keyword preceding the type in the argument list. The others are fine with taking pointers to const types since  CTVPtr is a pointer to const data.

I think the confusion came from the const key word you used which actually meant func3 will not change the data pointed by p rather than saying func3 will accept a const TVPtr.

If you really want to pass address of i to func3, you can cast it like this

```
func3( (void*)&i);
```